# Appending data fetched by an AJAX call to an already existing list for lazy-loading

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

I am pretty new to UI development, so please, bear with me. I am trying to implement lazy-loading on a webpage. That is, when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, a page is fetched from the server using an AJAX call. What is wish to do is to append the new data to the already existing one. Currently, the new data occupies the entire list-view and the scroll bar moves to the top. Here is my code:

AJAX call:

```
$scope.getMoreData=function(){
      updateAjaxData();
      var url=$scope.getURL();
      A.ajax(url, {
          method: 'post',
          params: AJAX_DATA,
          success: function(data, s, x) {
              $scope.providersList = JSON.parse(data.serviceproviderlist);
              $scope.serviceName = data.category;
              $scope.limit = SEARCH_LIMIT;
              $scope.$apply();
              var div = document.getElementById("spn-service-provider-list");
              var content = document.createTextNode($scope.providersList);
              div.appendChild(content);
          },
          error: function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown) {
              $scope.errorCallback(xhr);
          }
     });
  }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="spn-service-provider-list">
    <div class="spnsearch">
        <i class="spnicon spn-icon-search"></i> 
                <input type="search" ng-model="spsearch" id="spsearch" placeholder="Search Providers" name="spsearch">
    </div>
    <div id="spn-list" style="height:100vh;overflow-y:scroll;" when-scrolled="showMoreItems(filteredproducts.length,limit)">
            <div ng-repeat="providersList in ( filteredproducts = ( providersList | filter:{ providerName: spsearch } | filter:{ citiesServicing: locationsearch }:ignoreNullComparator ))  | orderBy: 'rank' | limitTo: limit " >
            ...................
            ...................
```

The problem is that when the new page is fetched using the AJAX call, it occupies the entire list-view. That is, the old list completely vanishes, and the new list occupies its place, with the scroll bar moving to the top.
Further, what is appending to my list successfully is a couple of **[object]**

Here is the code suggested, still, no change:

```
success: function(data, s, x) {
              if($scope.providersList === null) {
                $scope.providersList = []; /* init if null */
              }
              /* Update the existing array */
              Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.providersList, JSON.parse(data.serviceproviderlist));
              $scope.serviceName = data.category;
              $scope.limit = SEARCH_LIMIT;
              $scope.$apply();
              viewToBeDisplayed(LIST_VIEW);
          },
```

Comment: You might want to add to to the list that you display with `ng-repeat`? You are overriding the whole angular-specific code when appending the content to the root element `#spn-service-provider-list`. You should append it to the `providersList` so that angular can update the view due to the change inside ng-repeat.

Comment: Can you have a look at the edited code? This time, I am appending it to $scope.providersList, as suggested by ValLeNain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you erase your existing array.
So replace

`$scope.providersList = JSON.parse(data.serviceproviderlist);`

with

```
if($scope.providersList == null) {
  $scope.providersList = []; /* init if null */
}
/* Update the existing array */
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.providersList, JSON.parse(data.serviceproviderlist));
```

Comment: Trying that out now.

Comment: I have added the code you gave. Still, it is occupying the whole view.

Comment: can you scroll and view both the old data and the new data ? If so, where would you like the scrollbar to be, at the bottom (and so you see the new data, or at the top, and so you see the old data) ? (if not sensitive data, please add screenshots)

Comment: When I scroll down, the scroll bar moves to the extreme top. No previous data are visible. I can't seen any item from the previous list. I am so sorry, I can't add screenshots without permission. I would like the scroll-bar to move up only a bit, so that the some of the old list is still visible.

Comment: ahah, happens sometimes :) Also check that is not because of the filters you apply on the providersList